# Using pixi-multistyle-text Pixi.js - change char color within a string

Tags: string, typescript, colors, pixi.js

I'm very new to this and am seeking some explanation/brief guide.

I'm using Pixi.js. I only want to effect certain characters within a string, altering the colour and making some of the characters bold, but not effecting the string as a whole.

I understand this repo GitHub.com/tleunen/pixi-multistyle-text allows you to add XML tags to strings to do this.
What I don't understand is how I can use it on my machine. (I have a moderate understanding of git) but do not know how to use this repo within my currently separate project.

Do I simply need to clone the repo, then copy paste its source file to my project?

I also am not familiar with
$ yarn install
Or
$ yarn build
And when I try to use these within the terminal in code I get many errors!

Anything is appreciated.
(I have limited experience doing gamedev personal projects as a hobby, have never attempted a full 'web dev' project before)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do not want to build it, but you can access or download the distribution files from here:

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/pixi-multistyle-text